# Not able to find the pages after running Node server on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, server, nodejs

I am not able to get the pages even if my node server is also running.Please take a look on the below snap shot.

[image: ![enter image description here]

After running the server when i typed the ip address and port number `i.e-8888` in browser's address bar the pages are not coming.It is showing the message `This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did not have the make tools available when you installed your mongodb library. I suggest you do

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make build-essential
```

and run

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

OR just npm update

```
npm update
```

Edit 1

In the file `node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js`, change the line

```
bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
```

to

```
bson = require('bson');
```

Comment: @2707074: I have already followed your all commands and removed that error also but issue is again there.I am updating my snap shot again.

Comment: You can check my post again.

Comment: I edited my answer and add more code.

Comment: i am using mongojs.

Comment: I did that but still issue is there.One thing i can say i run command `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` to check listen ports and i saw my 8888 port is running but i can not get any pages.

Comment: Is there any other answer to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You never specified exactly which URL you're trying to access. It should be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

Note that there's a colon between the IP and the port, not a dash.

To confirm that the browser actually reaches the server check if there's any output in the console when you hit Enter after typing in the URL in the browser.

Comment: @satya If the answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @ Sergey : No,I got later that problem was in my system.